# android Listview

Tags: android

i am using list view to store date in sqlite database. In that the driver taking one trip.In that trip contain number of stops( Delivery, Begining of break, End of break, Begining of lunch, End of lunch, End of Trip). If i add the Begining of trip, all other stops will be added inside the trip,,,,, until the end of the trip......

Problem is
I have 2 pages first page having some listview.when i click the first row of the listview it show another set of listview in 2nd page. so each row in the main listview(1st page) have corresponging set of sub listview(2nd page) in the secong page.

All the stops are showing in the same page... any one help for my problem

Comment: What is your problem? Your question is not clear (I have no idea what your application / part should do), and where is the part that you have problem with from the description above. Some code snippets would be great for demonstrating the issue. And also, please clear up your goal. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the point regarding your problem. I think you want to have listview where you click on any trip item from trip listview and it display sub-items related with clicked item.

If my above assumption is right, then you should implement [**`ExpandableListView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Here are the examples which you can refers to and get more idea:

- http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/
- http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is I have 2 pages first page having some listview.when i click the first row of the listview it show another set of listview in 2nd page. so each row in the main listview(1st page) have corresponging set of sub listview(2nd page) in the secong page.

In your case you have to use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

check below below links, hope it will help you!

[How to use ExpandableListView](http://androidword.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-expandablelistview.html)

[Custom Expandable Listview](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html)

[Android Expandable ListView simple Example in android.](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

[How to create a custom ExpandableListView](http://androidexperiences.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/how-to-create-a-custom-expandablelistview-2/)

[Android-SlideExpandableListView](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView)